# Using middleware with Golang Gorilla mux subrouters

Tags: go, middleware

How can I apply middleware to a Go [Gorilla Toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/) mux subrouter?

I have the following code:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
apiRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api/").Subrouter()

apiRouter.Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/api/path/to/handler").Handler(handleAPICall)
```

I want to apply a middleware handler that checks a security token, but only on those paths that start with `/api`.

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/360#issuecomment-584869714) is helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
apiRouter := mux.NewRouter()

router.PathPrefix("/api/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/api",
    adapt(apiRouter, checkTokenHandler)))

apiRouter.Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/path/to/handler").Handler(handleAPICall)
// Note that `/api` has been removed from the path.
```

where

```
func adapt(h http.Handler, adapters ...func(http.Handler) http.Handler)
    http.Handler {
    for _, adapter := range adapters {
        h = adapter(h)
    }
    return h
}
```

and

```
func checkTokenHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // Check the security cookie.
        h.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
}
```

Comment: A little late to the party, but this doesn't actually user the Subrouter from Gorilla Mux...

Answer (score 1):

use these code ,should work fine

```
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    api := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
    routes.InitRouteV1(api)

    // handle 404
    r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json")
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&response.Rsp{Code: http.StatusNotFound,Message: http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound) })
    })
     // handle method
    r.MethodNotAllowedHandler = http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json")
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&response.Rsp{Code: http.StatusMethodNotAllowed,Message: http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed) })
    })
```

```
package routes

func InitRouteV1(r *mux.Router){
    r.Use(middleware.ResponseJsonMiddleware)
    r.HandleFunc("/user", controller.User).Methods("GET")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```golang
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

apiRoutes := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
apiRoutes.Use(authMiddleware)
apiRoutes.HandleFunc("/postes", getPostes).Methods("GET")
apiRoutes.HandleFunc("/postes/new", newPost).Methods("POST")
```

this is my authMidelware:

```golang
func authMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    if len(APP_KEY) == 0 {
        log.Fatal("HTTP server unable to start, expected an APP_KEY for JWT auth")
    }
    jwtMiddleware := jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
        ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte(APP_KEY), nil
        },
        SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
    })
    return jwtMiddleware.Handler(next)
}
```